# Drag and drop files with cURL

Tags: curl

I know that curl supports file upload e.g. [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#File_Upload_POST). Is it possible to upload files to site which has HTML5 Drag and Drop box for file uploading

Comment: What exactly you mean by *HTML5 Drag and Drop box*?

Comment: @peterph I mean area where you can upload file by dropping file from desktop

Comment: It's not possible to do that as a drag and drop operation with `curl`. You'd have to script it via the command line, but it should be scriptable.

Comment: If you mean the standard file upload field (i.e. `<input type="file" />`, then it's not really HTML5 Drag and Drop. Merely the browser allows you to put a value in that field in a special manner.

Comment: @slm one can certainly pin together a simple drag'n'drop-capable application in a scripting language (Perl/Python/Ruby/...) which would call `curl` on it's input.

Comment: @peterph - obviously, I wasn't saying that it was impossible, just not possible "out of the box" with curl.

Comment: Yes - the point here is that curl is a *command line* utility and can only process command line arguments and standard input.